# Find all combinations of 0, 1 that sum to 1 or 2 at varying lengths / sizes

Tags: python, recursion, combinations, permutation

I would like a function that would return 0, 1 combinations, that sum to 1 or 2, for varying length.
I know the total combinations (before removing the summations) follow 2**length.

Example:
length = 4

Result:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 1],
[1, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 1, 0, 0]]
```

I was able to use a recursive function to get up to lengths of 10.
After that, python crashes due to recursion limit.

I did try increasing it, but this still results in the program crashing. I would like to be able to do all combinations that sum to 1 or 2 up to a length of 40.

That code is listed below:

```
def recursive_comb(bits):
     """Creates all possible combinations of 0 & 1
     for a given length
     """
     test = []

     def calc_bits(bits, n=0):
         if n.bit_length() <= bits:
             comb_str = '{:0{}b}'.format(n, bits)
             comb_list = [int(elem) for elem in comb_str]
             test.append(comb_list) 
             calc_bits(bits, n + 1)

     calc_bits(bits)

     return test

all_comb = recursive_comb(4)

all_comb = [elem for elem in all_comb if ((sum(elem) == 1) or (sum(elem) == 2))]
```

Comment: Since you are programming in Python, presumably you understand that indentation affects the meaning of the code. Wrongly indented code does not make sense and cannot be run. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It's now fixed. Copying code to Stackoverflow is terrible. Unless, there is a way I'm missing, the formatting never sticks.

Comment: For next time, you only need to post your code and then put ``` above and below it. Pasting code here does not alter its indentation.

Comment: Ah gotcha, thanks! I always used the curly braces or "ctrl + k". I just tested out the ``` and that works like charm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you don't mind using an external library ([`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/)) you could use this:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations

length = 4
for n in range(1, 3):
    lst = [1] * n + [0] * (length - n)
    for perm in multiset_permutations(lst):
        print(perm)
```

[`multiset_permutations`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations) generates all distinct permutations of a list with elements that are not pairwise different. i use this for lists with the desired numbers of `0` and `1`.

if your lists contain many elements this will be much more efficient that just go through all possible permutations and discard the duplicates using a `set`.

Comment: Yes, this was super fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do it like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

length = 4
result = {p for p in permutations([0, 1]*length, length) if sum(p) in [1, 2]}

print(result)

# output:
# {(0, 0, 0, 1),
#  (0, 0, 1, 0),
#  (0, 0, 1, 1),
#  (0, 1, 0, 0),
#  (0, 1, 0, 1),
#  (0, 1, 1, 0),
#  (1, 0, 0, 0),
#  (1, 0, 0, 1),
#  (1, 0, 1, 0),
#  (1, 1, 0, 0)}
```

The resulting set contains all permutations that sum up to 1 or 2.

There is some redundant computations done in `permutations`, so it may take a while depending on `length`, but you shouldn't run into recursion / memory errors.

Comment: The accepted answer is much more efficient. Therefore considering the OP wanted to generate a list with 40 elements, looking at all `2**40` permutations and checking the sum is, IMHO, not really a solution to find the 820 he requires.

Comment: I think the number of permutations considered here is `(2n!)/(n!)`. For `n=40`, this is much larger than `2^40` (a number with 71 digits).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution with `itertools`. For each length `n`, choose `k` positions for ones in `combinations(n, k)` ways. This approach is less general `multiset_permutations` from `sympy`, but is faster for this specific case:

```
import itertools

# notation:
# n: length of a sequence
# k: number of ones

def f(n, ks):
  for k in ks:
    for idx in itertools.combinations(range(n), k):
      buf = [0] * n
      for i in idx:
        buf[i] = 1
      yield buf

result = list(f(4, [1,2]))
```

Comparison with 20x speedup:

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations


def g(n, ks):
  length = n
  for k in ks:
    lst = [1] * k + [0] * (n - k)
    for perm in multiset_permutations(lst):
        yield(perm)

assert sum(1 for _ in f(20, [1,2,3])) == sum(1 for _ in g(20, [1,2,3]))
%timeit sum(1 for _ in g(20, [1,2,3])) # 10ms
%timeit sum(1 for _ in f(20, [1,2,3])) # 500µs
```